# Extract Some Part Of String with mysql Query

Tags: mysql

I have table contains data from sms, the value like

```
Info Gempa Mag:5.7, 17-Jan-19 09:53:02 WIB, 
Lok:7.09 LU,93.97 BT (202 km BaratLaut KOTA-SABANG-ACEH), Kedlmn:165 Km ::BMKG
```

each value has different string (which is city or region name), the only different like

```
KOTA-SABANG-ACEH
SUMBATENGAH-NTT
KULONPROGO-DIY
PEG-BINTANG-PAPUA
```

those string has various length

I need to extract those string, could it be done without installing any mysql plugins?

I'm using `10.3.11-MariaDB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for now, I'm use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to  find the value, for me it's enough for now, please let me know if you guys have better solution, i know there is better way to solve this.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TextDecoded, '(', -1),')', 1),' ', -1) from trx_dvb
```

Comment: I got the required substring using susbtr, instr and rev - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=785c27637cf91c7d8e08b0f5d809625b  but you have a better solution